# Как сделать градиент элементу <cricle/> в <svg>

Tags: html, css, svg

Вопрос мой состоит в том, что нужно чтобы оранжевая полоса стала как на картинке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проблема в том, что как бы я не вставлял градиент, он попросту не применяется, а с svg я знаком очень плохо и не могу найти причину и сделать так, как нужно.
Может кто поможет с этим? Так же, это эдакий progress bar, который будет заполнятся постепенно, если кто знает, скажите, возможно я делаю что-то неправильно?

```css
.gradient {
  background-image: 
  linear-gradient(to left, #0065ff 0%, #733adc 100%);

}
.stp1 {
  stop-color: #0065ff;
}
.stp2 {
  stop-color: #733adc;
}
.progress-bar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 200 200" class="progress-bar">
 <circle r="80" cx="100" cy="100" fill="none" stroke-width="12" stroke="#ccc"/>
 <circle r="80" cx="100" cy="100" fill="none" stroke-width="12" stroke="orangered"
   stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="406 502.4"
   stroke-dashoffset="-20" class="gradient"
   fill="url(#linear-gradient)" />
<text x="100" y="125" font-family="Arial" font-size="70"
      text-anchor="middle" fill="#444">
      75
      </text>
     <defs>
      <linearGradient id="linear-gradient">
            <stop offset="0%" class="stp1"/>
            <stop offset="100%" class="stp2"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
         
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказывается я ошибся в одном из параметров по незнанию SVG, вам просто стоит задать градиент через  `<linearGradient>` и в атрибуте stroke у полосы прогресса (которая и будет цветной) указать url градиента

```css
.gradient {
  background-image: 
  linear-gradient(to left, #0065ff 0%, #733adc 100%);

}
.stp1 {
  stop-color: #0065ff;
}
.stp2 {
  stop-color: #733adc;
}
.progress-bar {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 200 200" class="progress-bar">
 <circle r="80" cx="100" cy="100" fill="none" stroke-width="12" stroke="#ccc"/>
 <circle r="80" cx="100" cy="100" fill="none" stroke-width="12" stroke="url(#linear-gradient)"
   stroke-linecap="round" stroke-dasharray="406 502.4"
   stroke-dashoffset="-20" class="gradient"
   fill="none" />
<text x="100" y="125" font-family="Arial" font-size="70"
      text-anchor="middle" fill="#444">
      75
      </text>
     <defs>
      <linearGradient id="linear-gradient">
            <stop offset="0%" class="stp1"/>
            <stop offset="100%" class="stp2"/>
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
         
</svg>
```